# CardView elevation shadow not centered?

Tags: android, android-cardview, androidx

I have a `CardView` defined as

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="35dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_user_default"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

But somehow I am getting this weird shadow, which I am not able to figure out why?
[image]

I wanted to have a circular CardView with a circular shadow around it, but instead I am getting a shadow in the right bottom corner.

What am I missing out?

I tried few things and this is what I concluded.

CardView is inside a RelativeLayout which has `wrap_content` as `layout_height`. Which I guess is wrapping the CardView only, without it's shadow. Take a look at below example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="35dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="35dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Which will show like
[image]

So that leads to a question why it's wrapping around the CardView but not CardView with its shadows? 
And one side question. How do you center the shadow of CardView? If you look closely to the second CardView, the shadow is has a gravity to bottom.

Comment: is Image `PNG`?

Comment: please check this sample snippet [here](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-how-to-set-cardview-elevation.html)

Comment: What's the Android version of your device? The image is circular? How are you loading this image in the cardview?

Comment: @aliusman image is not `png`. Its `jpg`

Comment: @snti I am using Android 8. Image is not circular. I am loading it by assigning `src` and since it's inside cardview it will be circular.

Comment: Upload your image - If it's not PNG then it will have a background (that's what you see) as it is not possible for the image to be displayed in circle like this unless the background is made transparent which can only be done in PNG (AFAIK)

Comment: It's NOT related to image. Image is inside cardview. So it has nothing to do with with a shadow outside cardview. Remove the image, I am still getting that shadow.

Comment: What is the parent of this cardView? Looks like the parent is clipping the shadow. Can you try with elevation 5 or 3 and margin 10 to the cardView and see what happens?

Comment: @IshitaSinha Indeed the problem was the parent of it. I just updated the question with few more tries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [android documentation for shadows](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping).

You said:

*CardView is inside a RelativeLayout which has `wrap_content` as `layout_height`. Which I guess is wrapping the CardView only, without it's shadow. So that leads to a question why it's wrapping around the CardView but not CardView with its shadows?*

The following answers why:

> Shadows are drawn by the parent of the elevated view, and thus subject to standard view clipping, clipped by the parent by default.

Also:

> The bounds of a view's background drawable determine the default shape of its shadow. Consider this view, defined with a background drawable:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    ...
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/myrect" />
```

> The background drawable is defined as a rectangle with rounded corners:

```
<!-- res/drawable/myrect.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#42000000" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

> The view casts a shadow with rounded corners, since the background drawable defines the view's outline. Providing a custom outline overrides the default shape of a view's shadow.

This you have already achieved with `app:cardCornerRadius="35dp"` rather than a custom background drawable (which is equally acceptable, although I thought adding this bit of info might be of some additional help if you need it for other views in the future).

To answer the question *How do you center the shadow of CardView?* you may take a look at the [material design guidelines](https://material.io/design/environment/light-shadows.html#shadows). According to Material Design, shadows should come from both ambient light (front light source) and a key light (top light source):

[image]

The elevation of these light sources are by default 90 degrees and 45 degrees respectively in the android framework, and cannot be changed because that would be inconsistent with material design. However, if you want to create a custom shadow with a custom angle, you could use a gradient drawable and set that as a shadow as described [here](https://medium.com/@ArmanSo/take-control-of-views-shadow-android-c6b35ba573e9) under the head ***Using Shape Drawable (New way to implement shadow)***.

Basically, you need to use the `setShadowLayer` method from the `android.graphics.Paint` class.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The deviation of `CardView`'s shadow depends on its location in screen. As you can see in below picture, when the `CardView` is placed in left or right side of the screen, its shadow is deviated to left or right side too.

[image]

However, AFAIK, we have no control on the `CardView`'s shadow perspective since there is no attribute for it to change. If you want to have a custom direction shadow, you should do it yourself.